# Chamisha Ve'esrim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred twenty-five?

### ?חמישה ועשרים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 325? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 325, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

If you see lazy gematrias for this number and think that thus is how you come up with a high-quality answer, think again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kainan קינן was born 325 years after the world was created.

Adam fathered Sheis in year 130.

Sheis fathered Enosh 105 years later in the year 235.

Enosh fathered Kainan 90 years later in the year 325.

Answer (score 4):

There are at most 325 days on which work is permitted per year, for those who live in Israel. This occurs in a [leap year starting on Shabbos, where Cheshvan and Kislev each have 30 days](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%AA_%D7%96%D7%A9%D7%94).

```
 385 days in the year
- 55 Shabbasos
-  8 days of Yom Tov
+  3 days of Yom Tov and Shabbos, which were double counted:
                                  Rosh Hashanah, Succos, and Shemini Atzeres
----
 325 workdays
```